# How to prevent User from creating duplicate values using React-Select Creatable?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select' `Creatable` to make a dropdown and allow user to create new item to the list.

This is what I have:

```
<Creatable
  name="form-field-name"
  value={this.props.selectWorker}
  options={this.props.selectWorkers}
  onChange={this.props.handleSelectWorker}
/>
```

Right now user can create new name even though it already exist, creating duplicates like shown below.

[image: Duplicate name]

I saw that there is an option called `isOptionUnique` on [react-select site](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select).

> Searches for any matching option within the set of options. This
>   function prevents duplicate options from being created. By default
>   this is a basic, case-sensitive comparison of label and value.
>   Expected signature: ({ option: Object, options: Array, labelKey:
>   string, valueKey: string }): boolean

I have not been able to use it. I have tried `isOptionUnique=true`, `isOptionUnique={options:this.props.workers}`, but I got `Creatable.js:173 Uncaught TypeError: isOptionUnique is not a function` error.

I can't find an example for `isOptionUnique`, what is the best way to filter react-select to prevent duplicates using `Creatable`?

Answer (score 2):

It's expecting a function

```
isOptionUnique(prop) {
  const { option, options, valueKey, labelKey } = prop;
  return !options.find(opt => option[valueKey] === opt[valueKey])
}
```

Don't forget to add it to your component instance

```
isOptionUnique={this.isOptionUnique}
```

Comment: Is this case sensitive? The creatable ignoreCase option does not seem to work, so I'm wondering, if I could prevent duplicates with differing cases with this.

Comment: Im not sure if this helps, but ignoreCase defaults to `true` which should ignore case by default when filtering the results. (So `'true'` is the same as `'TruE'` by default) Also if you have filterOption(s) set it will override ignoreCase. At least that's what the docs on github say. https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

Comment: oh but, yes, this is definitely case sensitive. The comparison is done and returns a boolean, so you could modify it easily. It would probably do as you said, and Im just guessing there would be no side effects.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be achieved using the `isValidNewOption` prop.

```
isValidNewOption = (inputValue, selectValue, selectOptions) => {
    if (
      inputValue.trim().length === 0 ||
      selectOptions.find(option => option.email === inputValue)
    ) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

you define a function taking three parameter of the inputValue you typed in, the selectValue if a value is selected and the existing options as `selectOptions`.
The function should return true or false dependent on what conditions you want a new option to be valid. this will prevent addition of duplicates.

In the case above we prevent adding of new options if there is no text or if the email already exists in the available options

Comment: Adds new option even though method return false.

Comment: This method will prevent the option "Create abcd..." from appearing in the select list. If the false option is not shown.